# Paralleling python 'for' loop with 'if' statement using tensorFlow

Tags: python, for-loop, tensorflow, if-statement

Could anyone please help convert this code to TensorFlow? I am attempting to find the data point positions in the set for which the CNN outputs a value bigger than 0.95, so as to aid in pseudo-labeling.

```
   positions = []

   for t in range(int(dataset.shape[0] // batch_size)):
        data = dataset.next_batch
        model_output = sess.run([output], feed_dict={model_input_pl: data})

        for i in range(model_output[0].shape[0]):
            if model_output[0][i][some_nodal_position] > 0.95:
                 positions.append(batch_start_position + i)
```

Paralleling this code would allow for many more models to be tested, but having the code as above takes a long time.

Comment: Would something along the lines of `tf.where(tf.greater(output, 0.95))` make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be implemented as follows:

```
tf.where(tf.greater(output, 0.95))
```

This returns a tensor with the indices where `output` is greater than 0.95.